# XF skiasharp downloads corrupted PDF

Tags: pdf, xamarin.forms, skiasharp

I want to create PDF reports using Xamarin Forms. I have tried creating sample PDF usin `skiasharp` plugin. But I am facing strange problem.

PDF can be opened in Mobile Device(Android 10.0, API 29) very easily. but if I try to open same PDF in laptop then it shows error message saying **Can not open corrupted PDF**.

Also if we look at size of the PDF, It is 183 KB in device and 0KB in laptop.

**Code**

```
private void GenerateDocument()
        {
            try
            {
                var root = EnsureTempDataDirectory("CreatePdfSample");
                path = Path.Combine(root, $"{Guid.NewGuid():N}.pdf");
                
                if (!isSupported || (isSupported && File.Exists(path)))
                    return;

                var metadata = new SKDocumentPdfMetadata
                {
                    Author = "Cool Developer",
                    Creation = DateTime.Now,
                    Creator = "Cool Developer Library",
                    Keywords = "SkiaSharp, Sample, PDF, Developer, Library",
                    Modified = DateTime.Now,
                    Producer = "SkiaSharp",
                    Subject = "SkiaSharp Sample PDF",
                    Title = "Sample PDF",
                };

                var stream = SKFileWStream.OpenStream(path);
                var document = SKDocument.CreatePdf(path, metadata);

                if (document == null)
                {
                    isSupported = false;
                    return;
                }

                var paint = new SKPaint
                {
                    TextSize = 64.0f,
                    IsAntialias = true,
                    Color = 0xFF9CAFB7,
                    IsStroke = true,
                    StrokeWidth = 3,
                    TextAlign = SKTextAlign.Center
                };

                var pageWidth = 840;
                var pageHeight = 1188;

                // draw page 1
                using (var pdfCanvas = document.BeginPage(pageWidth, pageHeight))
                {
                    // draw button
                    var nextPagePaint = new SKPaint
                    {
                        IsAntialias = true,
                        TextSize = 16,
                        Color = SKColors.OrangeRed
                    };
                    var nextText = "Next Page >>";
                    var btn = new SKRect(pageWidth - nextPagePaint.MeasureText(nextText) - 24, 0, pageWidth, nextPagePaint.TextSize + 24);
                    pdfCanvas.DrawText(nextText, btn.Left + 12, btn.Bottom - 12, nextPagePaint);
                    // make button link
                    pdfCanvas.DrawLinkDestinationAnnotation(btn, "next-page");

                    // draw contents
                    pdfCanvas.DrawText("...PDF 1/2...", pageWidth / 2, pageHeight / 4, paint);
                    document.EndPage();
                }

                // draw page 2
                using (var pdfCanvas = document.BeginPage(pageWidth, pageHeight))
                {
                    // draw link destintion
                    pdfCanvas.DrawNamedDestinationAnnotation(SKPoint.Empty, "next-page");

                    // draw contents
                    pdfCanvas.DrawText("...PDF 2/2...", pageWidth / 2, pageHeight / 4, paint);
                    document.EndPage();
                }

                // end the doc
                document.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }
        }
```

For sample, I have taken reference from `Skiasharp` Sample available on github.
Any help would be appreciated

**Edit**

As I have Created folder named CreatePDFSample, path of the file is

```
/Internal Storage/Download/CreatePdfSample/8c134318ca8d49f59d7a57e244845107.pdf
```

One more thing I noted right now, One of the 10-12 files I have created is opening in laptop as well. It is also at the same path. I can't understand what might be issue here.

Thanks

Comment: "It is 183 KB in device and 0KB in laptop" - it sounds like the problem is in transferring the file from the device, not creating the file.

Comment: Ok, so for transferring, I tried sending that file to my colleague by Skype. On skype file is not sent from my side. Also sent file using Gmail to myself. I received that file, size is also same 183 KB on my laptop but still not able to open. :|

Comment: @GayatriGokhale Hi, you could have a check this line code `vpdfCanvas.DrawText...` whether be invoked.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT yes it's invoked. I can see PDF in my device. problem is I can't open it in my laptop. I am confused if its' really corrupted or not. If it is then why it can be opened in device ?

Comment: @GayatriGokhale Hi, what's the path of pdf? You could update it in question.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Hi, Please see edit

Comment: @GayatriGokhale Thanks. From shared path, we can see that it's a Internal Storage path, you could have a try with external storage path to check whehter it works.

Comment: @JuniorJiang-MSFT Thanks for your kind help. But Issue is resolved. I have not disposed that stream properly. that was causing issue Using `using` keyword did the trick.

Comment: @double-beep ohh.. I didn't know that. I will update with my answer.

Comment: @GayatriGokhale Glad solved! Remember to mark the answer when you have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not disposed of the stream correctly. The `using` keyword for stream solved the issue.